# Mongo updating large documents

Tags: python, arrays, performance, mongodb, document

I have been trying to design a system that stores time related data for a large number (>200k) of unique devices every 10 seconds or so. The basic document structure looks something like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectID('$some_mongo_id'),
    start: $start_epoch,
    end: $end_epoch
    identifier: $some_string,
    values: {
        'cpu': [
           [1, 2, 3, 4, ...],
           [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
        ]
    }
}
```

A few details probably not well explained by the above:

- We are pre-allocating the entirety of each array in values with null values to get around any padding / moving issues. I believe this is confirmed because the db stats paddingFactor is always something like 1.000000000029.
- The values array is multidimensional based on reading and observation that an array is actually more like a linked list internally to mongo, so this reduces the amount of walks that need to be performed for a given update. The structure is fairly arbitrary but for ease of imagination it's basically index 1 is hour, index 2 is quarter, index 3 is minute.
- We are updating the documents every 10 seconds and using positional update queries to put the new value into the correct spot in the array. Something like "$set: {'values.cpu.2.7': 1234}". Each update only queries a single document based on its unique identifier + start/end times (indexed and verified based on explain).

We are seeing vastly different performance depending on how large the document is. If the document spans a day in length, our throughput is X and is limited by disk IO. If the document spans an hour in length, our throughput is about 8X and is limited by CPU (collection locking as observed by mongostat). All other variables remain the same in these tests.

I found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/iiTn8_r5X3E) which is from around 2 years ago and seems to match what we're seeing but I haven't been able to find anything more recent and my google fu has run out.

My question then is:

- When mongo updates a document, does it dirty all the pages that the document spans and thus requires the OS to flush the whole thing vs just the page that the change happened on? It seems that way but I cannot confirm officially.
- Is there a better way to structure / do this so that the above isn't burning us? Using 1 hour documents is possible but is about 24x the index space of day long documents which in this case is quite large.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Technical bits:

Mongodb server 2.4.7
RHEL6 x86_64
python 2.6.6
pymongo 2.5.2-3

Comment: Try taking a look at http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb

Comment: Martin - Thanks for that link, great read. Funnily enough, we're actually doing almost the same thing! Except we're trying to use bigger spanning documents to reduce the index size. I'll add a comment there asking about that.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first part of the question, I really don't have an answer I can give and be 100% sure. I will dig more into it and get back to you. Might be worth digging around source code too.

Regarding the second part, not sure it will be a precise answer, but I hope my thoughts on the matter help you.

The first thing I noticed is you can save some space (and make documents slightly smaller) by abbreviating names:

```
{
    _id: ObjectID('$some_mongo_id'),
    s: $start_epoch,
    e: $end_epoch
    i: $some_string,
    v: {
        'cpu': [
           [1, 2, 3, 4, ...],
           [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
        ]
    }
}
```

If you can, abbreviate 'cpu' to 'c' too, and so on. Not sure if you have a lot of freedom with it though, depending on... name collisions. Reason I propose this should be obvious, for each document stored you store that string in it too. It's all about the small data too.

Between the two options, I would opt for 8X performance and be bound by cpu.

The main concern is that you need to avoid moving documents *as much as possible*. Your preallocation seems to work well, based on the padding stats you are giving.

Opting to use smaller documents seems the better option on another front; if you have to pay the cost of moving the document, you leave smaller holes and you need to find empty space of smaller size.

However, I believe the many more updates (factor of 24?) cause a lot more processing with each dataset (find document, lock, update, write, (+flush?) ). In between the two, there could be a "sweetspot" of performance, where the disk io and cpu dance nicely together. It would be worth testing that, if you have the luxury. If that isn't true, and 8X is indeed the best you can get, then you might need to start accepting that you probably hit the limit of what one machine can take.

If CPU is the bottleneck, my suggestion would be to upgrade the solution to use [shards](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-shards/). The combination of 'Identifier' and 'start' appears to be a good candidate for a shard key. (DO keep in mind that once you choose your shard key, you can NOT change it). Effectively, it will give you more than one systems that can perform writes, in a distributed manner document-wise. It will give you a lot of breathing space ermm... space-wise, but it might also increase your hosts exponentially.

Comment: Jinxcat - thanks for the tips on reducing the field names. This is something we're planning on taking a look at once we nail down the schema and API. We have tried sharding and the performance definitely increases though the performance ratio remains with same bottlenecks.